Bootstrap 5 multiple carousel cards shows only one card
I am working on an Angular 17 web app and using Bootstrap 5 to create multiple cards in a carousel. Unfortunately it's just showing 1 card instead of 4.
The result I am expecting will look like this: https://www.codeply.com/p/0CWffz76Q9
I used the same code (copy and paste) but cannot understand why getting different result.
Find below my code.
PACKAGE.JSON
{
  "bootstrap": "^5.3.1",
  "jquery": "^3.7.0"
}

ANGULAR.JSON
{
  "styles": [
     "src/styles.scss",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css",
     "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
     "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
     "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
  ]
}

HTML
<div class="container text-center my-5 bg-black">
  <div class="row mx-auto my-auto justify-content-center">
    <div id="recipeCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400/31f?text=1" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400/e66?text=2" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 2</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400/7d2?text=3" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 3</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400?text=4" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 4</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400/aba?text=5" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 5</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-img">
                <img src="//via.placeholder.com/500x400/fc0?text=6" class="img-fluid">
              </div>
              <div class="card-img-overlay">Slide 6</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next bg-transparent w-aut" href="#recipeCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div {
    display: none;
  }
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item > div:first-child {
    display: block;
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item.active,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
  display: flex;
}

/* medium and up screens */
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-end.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next {
    transform: translateX(25%);
  }

  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-start.active,
  .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
    transform: translateX(-25%);
  }
}

.carousel-inner .carousel-item-end,
.carousel-inner .carousel-item-start {
  transform: translateX(0);
}

JS
let items = document.querySelectorAll('.carousel .carousel-item')
items.forEach((el) => {
  const minPerSlide = 4
  let next = el.nextElementSibling
  for (var i=1; i<minPerSlide; i++) {
    if (!next) {
      // wrap carousel by using first child
      next = items[0]
    }
    let cloneChild = next.cloneNode(true)
    el.appendChild(cloneChild.children[0])
    next = next.nextElementSibling
  }
})

Could someone please help me understanding what I did wrong ?
Thank you

how are you using this code in angular, in which lifecycle hook, do you have any errors in console (also, bs5 doesn't need jquery, and you should load minified version of bs)

I don't have any error in the console.
I create a component, paste the html and js code in the html template, the css code in the css file.
I removed jquery dependancy, load minified version of bootstrap but the result does not change

try running JS code from the component, not template, try ngAfterViewInit() { ..^^ JS code here...} try including more reproducible code, so far there is no angular code at all..

I am getting the error below
TS2339: Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Node'.

have a read of How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
